# Sinon stub is being ignored outside of the test file

Tags: node.js, express, mocha.js, passport.js, sinon

I'm using mocha, chai, and sinon to test some authenticated API routes.  I'm using passport.authenticate() as middleware to authenticate the route:

```
const router = require('express').Router();
const passport = require('passport');

router.post('/route', 
            passport.authenticate('jwt', {session:false}), 
            function(req,res) {
                return res.status(200);
            });
module.exports = router;
```

Then, in my test suite, I am using sinon to stub out passport.authenticate calls:

```
const chai = require('chai');
const chaiHttp = require('chai-http');
const sinon = require('sinon');
const passport = require('passport');
const server = require('../../app');
const expect = chai.expect;

chai.use(chaiHttp);
describe('route', function() {
    before(function(done) {
        sinon.stub(passport, 'authenticate').callsFake(function(test, args) {
            console.log('Auth stub');
        });
        console.log('stub registered');
        passport.authenticate('jwt', {session:false});
        done();
    });
    after(function(done) {
        console.log('after hook');
        passport.authenticate.restore();
        done();
    });
    describe('POST /route', function() {
        it('should post', function(done) {
            console.log('starting test');
            chai.request(server)
                .post('/route')
                .end(function(err,res) {
                    expect(res).to.have.status(200);
                    done();
                });
         });
     });
});
```

Now, when I run the test suite, I see it print out the following:

```
  route
stub registered
Auth stub
    POST /route
starting test
      1) should post
after hook

1 failing

1) route
   POST /route
     should post:

   Uncaught AssertionError: expected { Object (_events, _eventsCount, ...) } to have status code 200 but got 401
```

From this, we can see that the after the stub is registered, I can call it in the test file and it is properly stubbed.  But when passport.authenticate() is called in route.post(), it is the actual passport.authenticate() and sends a response with status 401 because I'm not authenticated.

Any thoughts on what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

Your code calls `passport.authenticate` *as soon as it runs*, and it runs *as soon as it is required*.

Because you are requiring the code at the beginning of the test before the `stub` has been created your code ends up calling the real `passport.authenticate`.

In order for code like this to call the `stub` you must set up your `stub` *before you require your code*:

```js
const chai = require('chai');
const chaiHttp = require('chai-http');
const sinon = require('sinon');
const passport = require('passport');
// const server = require('../../app');  <= don't require your code here...
const expect = chai.expect;

chai.use(chaiHttp);
describe('route', function () {
  before(function (done) {
    sinon.stub(passport, 'authenticate').callsFake(function (test, args) {
      console.log('Auth stub');
    });
    console.log('stub registered');
    passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false });
    done();
  });
  after(function (done) {
    console.log('after hook');
    passport.authenticate.restore();
    done();
  });
  describe('POST /route', function () {
    it('should post', function (done) {
      console.log('starting test');
      const server = require('../../app');  // <= require it AFTER creating the stub
      chai.request(server)
        .post('/route')
        .end(function (err, res) {
          expect(res).to.have.status(200);
          done();
        });
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

One small note related to sinon stubbing, I manage to have it working using this syntax:

```
passport.authenticate = sinon.stub( passport, 'authenticate' )
  .returns(
    ( req, res, next ) => {

      const user = {
        username: 'test user',
        email: 'testuser@mail.com',
        displayName: 'Test User',
        provider: 'testCase',
        roles: [ 'admin' ]
      }

      req.user = user;

      next()
    }
  );
```

Main things are:

1. add user data into req.user
2. execute next() for code flow to continue into next middleware

To recap this is not a way to actually test your authentication strategy but to bypass it in case you want to test router results.